# Jquery selecting specific image in div

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple images within a div like

```
<div>
<li>
<img src="" class="avaliable_image">
</li>
<img src="" class="magnify">

</div>
```

I am trying to use Jquery to remove entirely the image with the class name `avaliable_image`,

```
 $(this).find('img').attr('class' ,'avaliable_image').remove();
```

instead however, it removes both images instead of one? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<li>`s should be nested in a `<ul>`, not a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('img.avaliable_image').remove();
```

See [class selector reference](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `.attr('class' ,'avaliable_image')` actually just attempts to set the value of the class attribute on both images (both matched via `.find('img')`), and then your chaining of `.remove()` will still act upon both images.

You want

```
$(this).find('img.available_image').remove();
```

instead (note the use of CSS selector rules in `find`).